# Magento 2.3 : I want to add my third party js link in layout.xml file .?

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, api

Can anyone tell me how to add third party js link in magento2.3. I want to add this in my layout.xml file and use in template file.

The resource from “http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/static/version1578470158/front_US/https://test.com/scripts/test.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.com/scripts/test.js"/>
  </head>
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pricespider.tagging.success" template="Devcrew_PriceSpider::success.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Comment: how you have added this cefore?

Comment: No, I added custom js file in xml file.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Please check my above code.

Comment: It is still showing same error.

Comment: i have added an answer please check

Comment: flush cache and then try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103018/discussion-between-waqar-ali-and-yousaf).

Answer (score 2):

in you  `layout.xml`
try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.pricespider.com/scripts/test.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```